# How effective is baiting Reapers into cannibalizing?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Cannibals have the ability to regenerate health by consuming other fallen enemies on the battlefield. Marauders resurrect allies and coat them in scab-like armor plating. While consuming or resurrecting, the synthetic creatures are vulnerable and won't act you.

Is it a valid risk / reward strategy to focus on taking down a Cannibal or two and **baiting** the other synthetic troops to consume or resurrect it? Then while baiting, unload on them before they can armor up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather say that it will be best to get ride of the marauders first, mainly because of their Ressurection and leadership skills.
An overload, (with evnetually the repetitive improvement to make damage to the surrounding units) then some shot in the head. Then just focus on the remaining marrauders.

That will kill one bird with two stone since the marauders will be canibalizing the marauder!

Answer (score 1):

As an infiltrator this is my favorite thing to do. Pick one of them off and then let the others run from cover and expose themselves for easy headshots. You just have to be careful, if you don't get them you will have more protected enemies.

**Pros:**

- Lots of easy kills and less return fire.
- Less ammo/grenades used then firing on enemies in cover
- Easy crowd control

**Cons:**

- Enemies that have an increase in protection (keep in mind this armor can be avoided when shooting the plated target, requires a skilled marksmen sometimes)

I'd say the pros beat the cons definitely.

Comment: Eh that looks terrible someone fix it for me my phone wont let me.