# Does shattering a frozen Reaper prevent his friends from eating him?

Tags: mass-effect-3

*Alternate Title: "How can I choose between The Raw and The Cooked?"*

Cannibals are the main Reaper ground enemy you encounter in Mass Effect 3, so called because they [devour the corpses of their fallen allies](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56986/5398) to regain armor and strength.

Disruptor and incendiary ammo both do an excellent job of killing them, but they leave a pesky buffet luncheon lying around for any [Fine Young Cannibals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_Young_Cannibals) who come along. I'm Not Satisfied by this. I don't have Liara's warp ammo (because She Drives Me Crazy), which means that I'm left with Cyro ammo, which - in contrast to The Flame and disruptor rounds - shatters enemies if I kill them while they are frozen.

It seems reasonable to assume that once an enemy has been shattered, It's O.K. to ignore him, but what if all I'm doing is turning them into convenient, bite-sized chunky salsa for their compadres to enjoy?

Suspicious Minds want to know: **Does shattering a frozen Reaper prevent his friends from eating him?**

Comment: Upvotes for answers to this question will be given solely on the amount of 80s song references the answer contains. :]

Comment: I'm pretty sure, as there are no remains when they're shattered..

Comment: But Suspicious Minds is a 60s song!

Comment: I'll be up burning the Midnight Oil trying to figure it out :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Freezing and Shattering, Burning, and Biotic Disintegration all permanently remove the corpse from play - no need to worry about Cannibals profiting from them.

Cannibals can't eat what they can't find!

> 80s song references 80s song references 80s song references 80s song references 80s ...

Comment: -1 not enough 80s song references

Comment: I don't know if biotic explosions destroy the corpse, usually they just get thrown around but remain intact

Comment: @yx. I was specifically talking about Warp (Reave too, perhaps?), which kills them by dissolving them into blue fire. (Think Banshee death animation)